# Callback call with Ion on Intent Service(android)

Tags: android, callback, intentservice, android-ion

In my application I want to send my recordings to the web site on backgroud. I've researched and I reached the conclusion that I should use and IntentService.

But this leads me to a problem, i cannot reach the callback of Ion inside the IntentService.

The callback is important because I want to delete the file after finishing the upload.

How can I make this?

This is my code:

```
    Ion.with(this)
            .load(ip_address)
            .setMultipartParameter("key", key)
            .setMultipartFile("audio_file", array_mp3[idx])
            .asJsonObject()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                    Log.d("BackS", "wifiteste - chega aqui ");
                    array_mp3[idx].delete();
                }
            });
```

I never reach that Log which means that i never delete the file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get it, why do you need to use `IntentService` exactly?

Comment: To do the uploads in the backgroud.
For what I understood, thats what IntentService is about, right?

Comment: here is the answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569473/making-http-call-using-ion-with-in-intent-service-gives-error-on-data-network)